Nuxt.js - Simple Vue transition behaving weirdly, simply not working
I'm creating a simple Vue transition between my routes in a blank nux Application, here's my app.vue:
<template>
  <div>
    <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
      <div :key="$route.path">
        <NuxtPage />
      </div>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>
<style>
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
</style>

This creates the main page to load, then I have 2 pages in routes /pages/page1.vue and pages/page2.vue, with the following content:
Page1:
<template>
  <NuxtLink to="/page2">To Page 2</NuxtLink>
</template>

Page2:
<template>
  <NuxtLink to="/page1">To Page 1</NuxtLink>
</template>

When clicking the link from one page to the other, instead of smoothly transitioning out and then the new content transitioning in, it flashes the new content in instantly, then performs the transition of the new content to itself, a very weird behaviour.
Any ideas of what's going on and what to do to fix?

Have you tried with .page-enter-active? Nuxt is a bit different from Vue because it has a principle of "pages", hence the framework behaves a bit differently.
